# Stripe token not getting attached to request body for Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am making a Rails App that allows users to become subscribing users for $X/yr and I am stuck on the subscriptions page where whatever I do the stripeToken doesn't get attached to the request and CreateSubscription.rb says "This customer has no attached payment source". My turbolinks is disabled.

My Stripe Logs say that it is getting a request with the POST body:
email: "raf6000@gmail.com"
plan: "praducks-yearly"
but the error is thrown as follows - as there is no source object attached to request -
error:
type: "invalid_request_error"
message: "This customer has no attached payment source"

**CreateSubscription.rb**

```
class CreateSubscription
  def self.call(plan, email_address, token)
    user, raw_token = CreateUser.call(email_address)

    subscription = Subscription.new(
      plan: plan,
      user: user
    )

    begin
      stripe_sub = nil
      if user.stripe_customer_id.blank?
        puts "Customer is new"
        puts token.nil?
        customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
          source: token,
          email: user.email,
          plan: plan.stripe_id,
        )
        user.stripe_customer_id = customer.id
        user.save!
        stripe_sub = customer.subscriptions.first
      else
        puts "Customer exists"
        customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(user.stripe_customer_id)
        # Check if the customer was a stripe customer, but had no source added
        # If no source then update customer here:-
        # if customer.sources.total_count == 0
        #   customer.source = token
        #   customer.save
        # end
        stripe_sub = customer.subscriptions.create(
          plan: plan.stripe_id
        )
      end

      subscription.stripe_id = stripe_sub.id

      subscription.save!
    rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
      subscription.errors[:base] << e.message
    end

    subscription
  end 
end
```

**CreateUser.rb**

```
class CreateUser
  def self.call(email_address)

    user = User.find_by(email: email_address)

    return user if user.present?

    raw_token, enc_token = Devise.token_generator.generate(
      User, :reset_password_token)
    password = SecureRandom.hex(32)

    user = User.create!(
      email: email_address,
      password: password,
      password_confirmation: password,
      reset_password_token: enc_token,
      reset_password_sent_at: Time.now
    )

    return user, raw_token
  end
end
```

**subscription.js**

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#payment-form').submit(function(event) {
    var $form = $(this);
    alert('CLICKED');
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

    return false;
  });
});

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
  var $form = $('#payment-form');

  if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    // response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
    // and submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};
```

**SubscriptionsController**

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :load_plans

  def index
    # if !current_user.subscription.nil?
    #   redirect_to edit_subscription_path
    # end
  end

  def new
    @subscription = Subscription.new
    @plan = Plan.find_by_id(params[:plan_id])
    if @plan.nil?
      redirect_to subscriptions_path, :notice => "Please select a plan first."
    end
  end

  def create
    @plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
    puts params[:stripeToken]
    @subscription = CreateSubscription.call(
      @plan,
      params[:email_address],
      params[:stripeToken]
    )
    if @subscription.errors.blank?
      flash[:notice] = 'Thank you for your upgrade! ' +
        'Enjoy your premium membership at Praducks.com. ' +
        'We also sent you an email with the details of your purchase.'
      redirect_to '/'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @subscription = current_user.subscription
    if @subscription.nil?
      redirect_to subscriptions_path, :notice => "Please join a membership before making changes"
    end
  end

  def update
    @subscription = current_user.subscription
    @subscription = ChangeSubscriptionCard.call(
      @subscription,
      params[:stripeToken]
      )
    if @subscription.errors.blank?
      flash[:notice] = 'Account updated!'
      redirect_to '/'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  protected

  def load_plans
    @plans = Plan.where(published: true).order('amount')
  end

  private

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def subscriptions_params
    params.require(:subscription).permit(:email_address, :stripeToken)
  end


end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<!--<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

<div class="col2">
  <div class="shoppingcart">
    <% unless @subscription.errors.blank? %>
      <%= @subscription.errors.full_messages.to_sentence %>
    <% end %>
    <h4 class="heading colr">Joining <%= @plan.name %></h4>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="cart_form">
      <div class="form_cont">
        <%= form_for @subscription, url: subscription_path, html: { id: 'payment-form' } do |f| %>
          <input type="hidden" name="plan_id" value="<%= @plan.id %>" />
          <input type="hidden" name="stripeEmail" value="<%= current_user.email %>" />
          <input type="hidden" name="email_address" value="<%= current_user.email %>" />
          <span class="payment-errors"></span>

          <%= f.label :Email_Address %>: <%= current_user.email %>
          <div class="clear"></div>

          <%= f.label :Card_Number %>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>*
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <%= f.label :CVC %>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>*
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <%= f.label :"Expiration (MM/YYYY)" %>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <input type="text" data-stripe="exp-month" placeholder="mm" id="exp" limit="2"/>
          <input type="text" data-stripe="exp-year" placeholder="yyyy" id="exp" limit="4"/>*
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <button type="submit">Join</button>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**application.html.erb**

```
  <title><%=  full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
  <% if params[:beta] == "1" %>
    <% session[:beta] = "1" %>
  <% end %>
  <!--CSS-->
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'  %>

  <!--<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', type: 'text/javascript'%>-->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/praducks-uploads/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/><!-- Prelang: Analytics / Google Analytics -->
  <%= analytics_init if Rails.env.production? or Rails.env.development? %>

  <!--Javascript-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>');
    });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/subscriptions.js"></script>

</head>
<body data-no-turbolink>
<div id ="wrapper_sec">

  <% if Rails.env.production? %>
    <% if session[:beta] == "1" %>
      <%= render partial: "elements/navbar" %>
      <%= bootstrap_flash %>
      <!-- Bread Crumb Section -->
      <%= render partial: "elements/crumbs" unless current_page?(root_url) %>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render partial: "elements/footer" %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render "layouts/comingsoon" %>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render partial: "elements/navbar" %>
    <%= bootstrap_flash %>
    <!-- Banner -->
    <%= render "elements/banner" if current_page?(root_url) %>
    <!-- Bread Crumb Section -->
    <%= render partial: "elements/crumbs" %>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="content_sec">
      <%= render "elements/leftnav" %>
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
    <%= render partial: "elements/footer" %>
  <% end %>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: If you're not seeing the token passed in the `params` object to your controller then it's probably something client side in the browser which isn't working correctly. In that case I would add a brakepoint to your `stripeResponseHandler` to check two things: make sure it gets called, make sure token is present and that it actually is submitted with the other params to the server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After running this code locally I saw a couple of things:

I noticed that subscriptions.js isn't being included using the rails helper method `javascript_include_tag`. Unless you've placed your script in your app's `public/js` folder than your script probably isn't on the page.

Assuming that you do have it in `public/js` and it is on the page, I noticed this error when submitting the form:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $form.find(...).prop is not a function
```

Because of this error, your submit handler never reaches the `return false` to prevent the form from submitting thus it submits without the stripe token.

The version of jquery that's on the page is 1.3.2 which `.prop` isn't available for which is the reason for this error.

If you don't want to upgrade your version of jquery you can replace `.prop` with `.attr`:

```
$form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);
```

becomes:

```
$form.find('button').attr('disabled', true);
```

Also, if you want to ensure that the form doesn't submit (assuming javascript is enabled) I typically add this line at the very beginning of my submit handler:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

This should ensure that your form doesn't submit. You can also remove the `return false` at the end of your handler as that would no longer be required.

Comment: Good catch! Would have been stuck for God knows how long if it wasn't for you. Thank you. Didn't know I was using an old version of jQuery. How were you able to see the error? I am complete Javascript noob so don't know how to debug a js file.

Comment: If you are using Google Chrome, this link will show you how to access Chrome DevTools: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

This link shows you how to debug javascript using Chrome DevTools: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

If you are new to javascript in general I would recommend that you learn it, you'll use it a lot when it comes to web development. Plus it's awesome. There are tons of tutorials out there! I would recommend you check out javascript.com (put together by codeschool)

Comment: @MrR You should mark this as solved if my answer got it working for you :)

Comment: @MrR in Firefox case, have a look at 'Firefox Developer Tools': https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Debugging_JavaScript