# This customer has no attached payment source

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I keep getting the same error of the customer has no attached payment source...
  I can't find out why this is.

```
attr_accessor :stripe_card_token

  def save_with_payment
    if valid?
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, source: stripe_card_token)
      self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
      save!
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include a specific technical question. As it is, no one can know what you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stripe token not getting attached to request body for Rails App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014977/stripe-token-not-getting-attached-to-request-body-for-rails-app)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have set the `attr_accessor` for `stripe card token`, but have you actually implemented the token generation procedure as mentioned in the stripe documentation https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#create_customer?

You could look at https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js on how to generate the token.

Comment: I did create a users.js file. How do I upload it here?

Comment: You should use that js to convert the credit card information to the token from js and pass to server as shown in https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js. then only you can use the token in `customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, source: stripe_card_token)`