# Ruby and Stripe API integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting the following error on my website. This is a part of course ala Ruby Boot-camp. I'm still learning and our tutor is saying that being able to solve problems and know how to look for help is important.

The following error happens when im pressing the Sign Up button on my page.

I also replaced all the code in my website with the one from the resource files that are associated with the course. By that I know i didn't make any typos, but still the error shows up.

```
**Stripe::InvalidRequestError in Users::RegistrationsController#create**
This customer has no attached payment source


` def save_with_payment
if valid?
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id,     card: stripe_card_token)
  self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
  save!
end`

Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/workspace/simplecodecasts_saas

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/user.rb:11:in `save_with_payment'
app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:8:in `block in create'
app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:4:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"**removed on purpose**",
 "plan"=>"2",
 "user"=>{"email"=>"stackoverflow@www.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

Comment: Does this issue apply to you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34256725/ruby-and-stripe-api-integration/34256841?noredirect=1#comment56255554_34256841

Comment: That's a link to this question and yes it does.

Comment: where is `stripe_card_token` defined? Are you sure it is not `nil`?

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong URL. This SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658425/this-customer-has-no-attached-payment-source mentions using the user.js profile to convert the credit card information to the token from js and passing to server

Answer (score 0):

Try setting source, instead of card.

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, source: stripe_card_token)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The Stripe API has changed. It could be that the bootcamp created the lesson before the update, and if you're using the Ruby 2.x/Rails4.x then you have to make a minor change here:

```
def save_with_payment
  if valid?
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
  self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
  save!
end
```

Change to

```
def save_with_payment
  if valid?
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, source: stripe_card_token)
  self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
  save!
end`
```

Alternatively, in case there are other issues with using different versions, you can set the Stripe API version to match the one being used in your course. Try setting the previous version by adding  `Stripe.api_version = '2015-01-11'` in the `config/initializers/your-config-filename.rb`.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. I still get the same error.

Comment: That also didn't help. I was going through the code backwards and i found that my users.js has an error: Stripe is not defined please fix or add /* GLOBAL STRIPE */ next to the line: Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content')); but in the header of the document everything looks fine.. I dont know if this might be causing it

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I am having the same issue and none of the post here are giving me a clue as to what the answer might be. Ask the same question would just be redundant.