# Stripe with Rails 4 Error "The Customer has no payment source" using stripe.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

When trying to submit a custom payment form (rendered by the subscription#new action) using stripe.js, I get the following error message: "The Customer has no payment source"

The form i'm submitting is:

```
<% unless @subscription.errors.blank? %>
  <%= @subscription.errors.full_messages.to_sentence %>
<% end %>

<h2>Subscribing to <%= @plan.name %></h2>

<%= form_for [:student, @subscription], html: { id: 'payment-form' } do |f| %>
  <input type="hidden" name="plan_id" value="<%= @plan.id %>" />
  <span class="payment-errors"></span>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Card Number</span>
      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>CVC</span>
      <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</span>
      <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month"/>
    </label>
    <span> / </span>
    <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year"/>
  </div>

  <button type="submit">Pay Now</button>
<% end %>
```

My subscriptions controller looks like:

```
class Student::SubscriptionsController < StudentApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:update]
  before_filter :load_plans 
  before_filter :find_plan, except: [:index]

  def index
  end

  def new
    @subscription = Subscription.new
  end

  def create
    if current_user.stripe_customer_id.blank?
      @subscription = CreateSubscription.call(
        @plan,
        current_user.email,
        params[:stripeToken]
        )
        if @subscription.errors.blank?
          flash[:notice] = 'Thank you for your purchase!' +
          'Please click the link in the email we just sent ' +
          'you to get started.'
          redirect_to '/'
        else
          render :new, notice: "Oops something went wrong"
        end
    else
      redirect_to new_student_subscription_path, notice: "You cannot create two subscriptions"
    end

  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
    @old_subscription = Subscription.find(current_user.subscription.id)
    @updated_subscription = ChangePlan.call(@old_subscription, @plan)
    if @updated_subscription.errors.blank?
      flash[:notice] = "You are now subscribed to the #{current_user.subscription.plan.name}"
      redirect_to '/'
    else
      render :new, notice: "Oops something went wrong"
    end
  end

  protected

    def load_plans
      @plans = Plan.all.order('amount')
    end

    def find_plan
      @plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
    end

end
```

The service object used in the create action is:

```
class CreateSubscription
  def self.call(plan, email_address, token)
    user, raw_token = CreateUser.call(email_address)

    subscription = Subscription.new(
      plan: plan,
      user: user
    )

    begin
      stripe_sub = nil
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        source: token,
        email: user.email,
        plan: plan.stripe_id,
      )
      user.stripe_customer_id = customer.id
      user.save!
      stripe_sub = customer.subscriptions.first

      subscription.stripe_id = stripe_sub.id
      subscription.expiry = Date.today + 1.month

      subscription.save!
    rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
      subscription.errors[:base] << e.message
    end

    subscription
  end 
end
```

In /app/assets/javascripts/students/subscriptions.js I have:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#payment-form').submit(function(event) {
    var $form = $(this);

     // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

     // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
    return false;
  });
});

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
  var $form = $('#payment-form');

  if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    // response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
    // and submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};
```

When submitting the custom payment form, params[:stripeToken] has a value of nil, so i'm not sure whether there is an error in the above jQuery code.

In app/views/layouts/application.html.erb I have:

```
<head>
  <title>OnlinePlatform</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>');
  });
  </script>
</head>
```

Can anyone help me identify why i'm getting the error message from Stripe?

Thanks

Comment: It definitely sounds like an issue with your javascript. Are you familiar with javascript and/or jquery and how to use your browser's javascript debugger?

Comment: And to answer your last question, you're seeing that error because the customer you're trying to create a subscription for doesn't have any cards saved to their stripe account. Since no payment source has been provided and there's no default source to fall back on (i.e. the customer has at least one card saved), Stripe returns the error that you're seeing.

To solve this problem, you have to figure out why `params[:stripeToken]` is nil (likely not being passed). Once you've solved that, you should be good to go.

Comment: I wonder if you're having a similar problem to this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014977/stripe-token-not-getting-attached-to-request-body-for-rails-app/31040255#31040255

What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Seems like I get an error on line 11 of the Javascript code where the following exception is thrown: "Reference Error: Stripe is not defined"

Comment: You're welcome to chat with me here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92336/33112756

Comment: Hi mark thanks for the tips. I've managed to figure out the problem. I have multiple layout files in my app and i was simply setting the Stripe publishable key in the wrong one.

Comment: right on, I've removed my previous comment and posted it as an answer. If you found that it helped you at all in solving the problem please feel free to mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

ok, so for one, your form submits without the token because an error occurs before the return false so it continues with the default behaviour. I would add `event.preventDefault();` as the first line of your submit handler to stop that from happening. Next, you need to figure out why Stripe hasn't been defined in the window object. I suspect turbolinks might play a role in that. Disable turbolinks for now to eliminate that as a variable then check to see if that script exists on the page and `window.Stripe` is defined using your browser's javascript console.